# How to capture clicks outside a modal dialog

Tags: winapi, mfc

I have a standard modal MFC dialog and I'd like to capture mouse clicks outside that dialog.

Is there a simple way to do this or do I have to transform the modal dialog into a modeless dialog?

Comment: Do you mean mouse clicks on other apps, or clicks on other parts of your app?

Comment: @JonathanPotter it doesn't really matter, clicks on other parts of the app would be enough.

Comment: Then making it modeless is probably the easiest way. Otherwise you'll need a mouse hook.

Comment: [SetCapture](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646262.aspx) might be an option, depending on the ultimate goal you're trying to achieve.

Comment: I tried SetCapture and it is making the app to catch mouse move events if the mouse is hover the other windows of the application. Outside, on other windows or on the desktop it doesn't make the app catch anything at all